# How to vertically align submit button with input box?

Tags: html, forms, alignment

basic html form BUTTON not aligned vertically with form input text field. it's off by ONE pixel. Doing this for a friend who is being picky and driving me nuts.
https://www.screencast.com/t/u8LBmH8b4

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: did you try this `position: relative; bottom: 1px` ?